# If a .gz file was downloaded can it demage my computer or steal data?

Tags: security

I was unaware that I was on a datafishing landing page (it was very clever, I haven't seen anything like this before) and I downloaded a .gz file. After that it started to become suspicius so I deleted the file and also get rid of it from the trash. I did not click on it and I did not unzipped it.

Considering this scenario, should I worry and make serious security steps and clean my computer or it can not harm my data (passwords) and my computer in any way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is unlikely that downloading alone may harm your machine. Executing file content could, but download itself should not (though there are some known exceptions to this statement: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Hafif-Reflected-File-Download-A-New-Web-Attack-Vector.pdf).